# Android Webview Focus problem with the keyboard

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to do the basics with the focus and the android keyboard. I have an App that has a WebView and a Button.

The webview has inputs, that will have the focus, but i don't want the keyboard to appear unleash the user touches the input. That's because i'm using it on a Zebra terminal, with a scanner.

I tried to do like this:

*activity_main.xml*

```
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
Button toggleKeyboard = findViewById(R.id.btnKeyboard);
        toggleKeyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!keyboardVisible){
                    try {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
                        WebView myWebView2 = findViewById(R.id.webview);
                        myWebView2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        keyboardVisible = true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }else{
                    try {
                        keyboardVisible = false;
                        WebView myWebView2 = findViewById(R.id.webview);
                        myWebView2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

That doesn't work. I can gain the focus and not show the keyboard the first time, but then it will show the keyboard everytime i gain a focus on the webview.

I think the problem is because of setFocusableInTouchMode doesn't work as supossed to.

Is there a way to hide forever the keyboard when i click the button without losing the focus?

Thank you!